# Не видит идентификаторов в main из класса

Tags: windows, классы, c++, visual-studio

Вроде все правильно, почему так? Что забыл? Не видит device, driver, smgr, guienv, camera, skybox, font.

```
#include "Game.h"
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "AILoad.h"
#include <cmath>
#include "StartGame.h"

using namespace irr;
using namespace gui;
using namespace core;
using namespace scene;
using namespace video;
using namespace io;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma comment(lib, "Irrlicht.lib")
#endif

class StartClass
{
public:
IrrlichtDevice* device;
video::IVideoDriver* driver;
scene::ISceneManager* smgr;
IGUIEnvironment* guienv;
scene::ICameraSceneNode* camera;
scene::ISceneNode* skybox;
gui::IGUIFont* font;
StartClass::StartClass()
{
    device = createDevice(video::EDT_OPENGL,core::dimension2d<u32>(800,600));
    driver = device->getVideoDriver();
    smgr = device->getSceneManager();
    guienv = device->getGUIEnvironment();  
    camera = smgr->addCameraSceneNodeFPS();
    skybox=smgr->addSkyBoxSceneNode(
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_up.jpg"),
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_dn.jpg"),
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_lf.jpg"),
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_rt.jpg"),
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_ft.jpg"),
    driver->getTexture("textures/skyboxes/Swamp/Swamp_sky_bk.jpg"));
    device->getCursorControl()->setVisible(false);
    font = device->getGUIEnvironment()->getFont("font/ddfont.png");
    driver->setTextureCreationFlag(video::ETCF_CREATE_MIP_MAPS, false);
    camera->setPosition(core::vector3df(0,0,0));
    camera->setFarValue(10000.0f);

}
};

int main()
{
AiSceneLoad<int>(1,0,0,0);

s32 lastFPS = -1;
    while(device->run())
    if (device->isWindowActive())
    {
        driver->beginScene(true, true, 0);

        smgr->drawAll();

        font->draw(L"Dark Dimension Pre-Alpha 0.1",
        core::rect<s32>(420,570,420,570),
        video::SColor(255,255,255,255));

        font->draw(L"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
        core::rect<s32>(0,0,0,0),
        video::SColor(255,255,255,255));

        driver->endScene();

        const s32 fps = driver->getFPS();

        if (lastFPS != fps)
        {
            core::stringw str = L"Dark dimension ";
            str += driver->getName();
            str += "] FPS:";
            str += fps;

            device->setWindowCaption(str.c_str());
            lastFPS = fps;
        }
    }

    device->drop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сначала создать объект класса StartClass, а потом уже обращаться к его свойствам.

Comment: Вот это прикол, после перезапуска компилятора заработало все, до этого не работало.